# Remaining days in the USA if you are laid off

Tags: usa, tn-visa

I am working under a TN visa and in the past weeks there have been some laid offs in my company, furthermore, if I am terminated then I want to know how many days can I remain legally in the USA before I have to go back to my home country.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are considered to remain in status until 60 days after you leave your job, or until your I-94 expires, whichever is sooner. [8 CFR 214.1(l)(2)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/8/214.1#l_2) says:

> An alien admitted or otherwise provided status in E-1, E-2, E-3, H-1B,
>   H-1B1, L-1, O-1 or TN classification and his or her dependents shall
>   not be considered to have failed to maintain nonimmigrant status
>   solely on the basis of a cessation of the employment on which the
>   alien's classification was based, for up to 60 consecutive days or
>   until the end of the authorized validity period, whichever is shorter,
>   once during each authorized validity period. DHS may eliminate or
>   shorten this 60-day period as a matter of discretion. Unless otherwise
>   authorized under 8 CFR 274a.12, the alien may not work during such a
>   period.

If you want to stay longer, you can file I-539 during this 60-day period to apply for Change of Status to B2 visitor status.